# Adding an additional JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to adjust stock code that pulls data from two tables, in order to add a column from a third table.

Here is the original query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, a.id as jobid 
from #__ja_jobs a 
LEFT JOIN #__users b 
ON a.user_id = b.id  
WHERE 1=1
```

I tried this approach, but it did not seem to work.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.user_id_value, a.id as jobid 
from #__ja_jobs a 
LEFT JOIN #__users b 
ON a.user_id = b.id  
WHERE 1=1
INNER JOIN #__ja_jobs_value c 
ON a.id = c.id`
```

And I tried to also move the `WHERE` statement at the end, but still no luck. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**:  All fixed!  I moved the WHERE to the end and then remembered a ridiculous rookie mistake - spaces at the end of all the lines.

Comment: Please provide example data, expected output and actual output. You may use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to make the answering easier for us :-)

Comment: The system uses columns from ja_jobs table to use in an XML feed.  One of the outputs I need, however, is the company name, which is in a third table, ja_jobs_value.  So I need to pull in user_id_value from the third table when the id matches between the first and third tables.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I _think_ this is how I would build a psuedo table situation for this:

`CREATE TABLE ja_jobs
(
user_id int,
id int,
Category varchar(255),
Location varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
id int
);

CREATE TABLE ja_jobs_value
(
id int,
user_id_value varchar(255)
);`

Running the query that I tried gives me this error which doesn't help:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version...